# Is there a tool for designing images for showcasing responsive websites?

Tags: web-apps, web-development

When showcasing a website or web-application, often the landing page will include a large image that shows the site on a number of different screen sizes, like that shown below.

Is there a service that helps do this (even from screenshots), or would I need to mock one up in Photoshop (or similar)?

[image]

Comment: Did someone already take the handle LegoStormtrooper ?

Comment: No, I made a name somewhere that had a 15 character limit once, so I dropped the last `e`. Its stuck, even on sites that have longer limits.